# Angular, CSS, HTML: Adding a backdrop that disable the whole DOM excepts for the popped up component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am looking for a way to lay down a shady layer on my whole DOM, disabling any controls inside of that (buttons, links, etc.), below the popped up window, as soon as the use clicks a button.

I just want a login form to appear, after the login button has been pressed, that will pop up in a panel in the middle of the screen and the user shouldn't be able to access any other part of the page, beside the login form.

The login button is a component that resides inside my navbar, which is another component.
The whole web app is made of 3 main components: navbar (where the menu and login button resides), body (where the web app content changes dynamically) and footer (where it is just, well... a footer!)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: simpyl use: `*:not('pop-up') {  pointer-events: none; overflow: hidden; }`. `pointer-events: none;` disable all clcikable elements and `overflow: hidden` disables the scroll ability

Comment: From the tags I assume that you use a material dialog for the login popup. If so, the config provides a hasBackdrop-property + optional backdrop class(es). See docs: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a container for your pop-up with these `css`:

```
.container {
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      margin:auto;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      z-index:99999;
    }
```

This is an example:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   z-index:99999;
}
.pop-up {
  position:absolute;
  width:90%;
  max-width:250px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
input {
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
 this is content of the web <br />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="pop-up">
    <input type="text" placeholder="user">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="log in">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is perfect Sir! Very appreciated. Could I ask you though, what does that *{box-sizing:border-box;} stand for? Thanks!!

Comment: When you add (it was just an example) width:100% (or any fixed value) to an element, by default the element will exclude these value from the size  property you give to it.  If You have padding-right:10px, and border-right:2px in an element with width:100px , in the DOM, the element will have a real width of 112px. Border-box revert this behaviour. In my example, just remove the property and you will see how the imput type submit won't take same width as the other inputs (as submit inputs have padding. border and more by browswer default)