# Creating background for an exit popup on a desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am right now working on a website where I have to create an exit popup for a couple of pages. I have created the popup, but the background of it stays active. So what's happening is that when I was testing it out, the popup shows once you move your cursor away from the window, which significates that the popup is working fine. But I was also expecting a kind of background blur so that when I open the popup, I want my background to stay dull or blur. I have tried a couple of times but failed. I have pasted the code below. Could anyone pitch in and help me out? Thanks in Advance!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
              <!-- jQuery cdn link -->
              <script src=
                             https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js>
              </script>
             
              <style type="text/css">
                             .content {
                                           position: fixed;
                                           top: 50%;
                                           left: 50%;
                                           
            background-image: url('');
                                           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                                           width: 500px;
                                           height: auto;
                                           text-align: center;
                                           box-sizing: border-box;
                                           padding: 15px;
                                           z-index: 100;
                                           display: none;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
                                           /to hide popup initially/
                             }
                            
                             .close-btn {
                                           position: absolute;
                                           right: 20px;
                                           top: 15px;
                                           color: white;
                                           border-radius: 50%;
                                           padding: 4px;
                                           cursor: pointer;
                             }
 
        .text-wrapper{
            margin:20px 60px;
        }
        .popup-text{
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .popup-text-small{
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .popup-text-large{
            font-size: 48px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        p{
            margin: 5px;
        }
        .box{
            border: 1px solid white;
            margin: 20px 50px;
        }
        .links{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin: 10px 50px;
        }
        .links a {
            border: 1px solid white;
            padding: 0 22px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            color: red;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
       
              </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 
 
              <!-- div containing the popup -->
              <div class="content">
                             <div class="close-btn">
                                           ×
                             </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
                             <p class="popup-text">Here you are!</p>
        <p class="popup-text-large">$ 12</p>
        <p class="popup-text">for your limited edition</p>
        <p> with CocaCola</p>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="" target="_self">Click Here to Subscribe</a>
            <a href="" target="_self">Click here to Login</a>
        </div>
        </div>
              </div>
 
              <script type="text/javascript">
             
                             // Function to show and hide the popup
                             function togglePopup() {
                                           jQuery(".content").toggle();
                             }
                             jQuery(window).on("mouseleave",function(){
if(jQuery('.content [class="text-wrapper"] .popup-text:visible').length==0 && typeof _satellite.cookie.get('popupshown')=='undefined'){
_satellite.cookie.set('popupshown',true);
togglePopup();
}
})
jQuery(document).on('click', '[class="close-btn"]', function(event) {
togglePopup();
})
              </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: check my answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754407/angular-css-html-adding-a-backdrop-that-disable-the-whole-dom-excepts-for-the/69754743#69754743

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a dull effect, I'd place a div for that and toggle it along the content:

```js
// Function to show and hide the popup
var popupshown //This is for replacing the cookie validation.

function togglePopup() {
  jQuery(".content").toggle();
  jQuery(".dull").toggle(); //toggle dull effect.
}

jQuery(window).on("mouseleave", function() {
  if (jQuery('.content [class="text-wrapper"] .popup-text:visible').length == 0 && typeof popupshown == 'undefined') {
    popupshown = true
    togglePopup();
  }
})
jQuery(document).on('click', '[class="close-btn"]', function(event) {
  togglePopup();
})
```

```css
.dull { /*Applies to the size of container, which is body.*/
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-wrapper {
  margin: 20px 60px;
}

.popup-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.popup-text-small {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popup-text-large {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 10px 50px;
}

.links a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 22px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: red;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dull"></div> <!--The effect is not a parent of content so we don't apply it to the popup-->
   <div class="content">
     <div class="close-btn">
       ×
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrapper">
       <p class="popup-text">Here you are!</p>
       <p class="popup-text-large">$ 12</p>
       <p class="popup-text">for your limited edition</p>
       <p> with CocaCola</p>
       <div class="links">
         <a href="" target="_self">Click Here to Subscribe</a>
         <a href="" target="_self">Click here to Login</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

If you apply a blur effect, you can use `filter: blur(2px)`, however, take into account that it will apply the filter only for the dull div's content, so elements in body wouldn't be affected. If you apply the filter directly to body, all elements, including the popup, would be affected by the blur effect. So, you'd have to work html inside a `.dull` div in order to get the effect in them.

```js
// Function to show and hide the popup
var popupshown //This is for replacing the cookie validation.

function togglePopup() {
  jQuery(".content").toggle();
  jQuery(".dull").css("filter", "blur(2px)") //apply blur effect when toggling popup.
}

jQuery(window).on("mouseleave", function() {
  if (jQuery('.content [class="text-wrapper"] .popup-text:visible').length == 0 && typeof popupshown == 'undefined') {
    popupshown = true
    togglePopup();
  }
})
jQuery(document).on('click', '[class="close-btn"]', function(event) {
  togglePopup();
})
```

```css
.content {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
}

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-wrapper {
  margin: 20px 60px;
}

.popup-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.popup-text-small {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popup-text-large {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 10px 50px;
}

.links a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 22px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: red;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="dull">
   THIS IS HTML CONTENT.
 </div>
 <!--div containing the popup-->
   <div class="content">
     <div class="close-btn">
       ×
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrapper">
       <p class="popup-text">Here you are!</p>
       <p class="popup-text-large">$ 12</p>
       <p class="popup-text">for your limited edition</p>
       <p> with CocaCola</p>
       <div class="links">
         <a href="" target="_self">Click Here to Subscribe</a>
         <a href="" target="_self">Click here to Login</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The blur effect did work for me.